# What is the proper emphasis for the word "indent"?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Does *indent* carry an accent on the first or the second vowel?

I've seen both in IPA. My non-native ear would tend to favor the first.

Comment: Purely subjective, but I'd put the accent on the first syllable for the noun sense, and on the second as a verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Likewise. Confirmed by dictionary references, so not so subjective.

Comment: I admit it was me who voted to close on the grounds I thought the question was "too localised". But I wouldn't have done that if I'd seen @Daniel's comment below - I now think there really *is* a general principle whereby noun/verb are often distinguished by stress on the first/second syllable, which it's worth being consciously aware of.

Comment: Related questions for [“record”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60327/why-is-the-verb-form-of-record-pronounced-ri-kawrd-but-the-noun-form-is-pron), [“defect”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/how-did-defect-and-defect-come-to-have-different-pronunciations).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I would say "*ind*-ent" for the noun, and "ind-*ent*" for the verb.

*Ind*-ent for the noun is pretty much universal.

For the verb, it varies from person to person. I don't perceive a geographical pattern.

Comment: + 1 : the obvious follow-up is does pronounciation rule  generalise to other noun/verb twins?

Comment: Most two-syllable words which can be nouns or verbs carry the emphasis on the first syllable as a noun, and on the second as a verb (cf. *address*, *combine*, etc), though I'm sure you could find exceptions in plenty, if you tried.

Comment: Interesting, I'd break the word up as in-DENT(v) or IN-dent(n), which is how the dictionary.com breaks it up (interestingly they don't show the verb form accented on the second syllable as an alternative but I think they should).  Is this a typo, or is the syllable separation regional?

Comment: I can't see how ind-ent would be pronounced differently from in-dent. My hyphen isn't intended imply a pause, and I don't think you can emphasise the consonant 'd'. So it was an arbitrary choice to put the hyphen right of the 'd'.